# How to get values from Helm locally without separate environment variable system?

Tags: python, kubernetes, environment-variables, kubernetes-helm

I have a Python application that is deployed using Helm and Kubernetes. I want to take hard-coded variables out of main.py and make them configurable in Helm. The trouble is if I pull them out of main.py then I lose the ability to run my code with `python3 main.py`. Then I lose the ability to test and iterate quickly because I need to maintain two separate systems for every parameter in 3-4 places.

#### `main.py` Before Extracting Hard-Coded Variables:

```
HOST = "http://host" 
PORT = 1234
if __name__ == '__main__':
    connect_to_server(HOST, PORT)
```

#### Newly created values.yaml

```
host: "http://host"
port: "1234"
```

#### Newly Template (e.g., bottom of containers in cronjob.yaml):

Using string for environment variable integer as per [Helm docs](https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#quote-strings-don-t-quote-integers).

```
env:
  - name: HOST
    value: {{ required "host is required!" .Values.host | quote }}
  - name: PORT
    value: {{ required "port is required!" .Values.port | quote }}
```

#### `main.py` After Extracting Hard-Coded Variables::

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        HOST = os.environ['HOST']
        PORT = int(os.environ['PORT'])
        connect_to_server(HOST, PORT)
    except IndexError as e:
        print("Unable to run app! No env vars defined outside Helm!")
        raise e
```

If I leave this setup above as is it will not run when I execute `python main.py`. **If I want to get this to run using plain old `python3 main.py` then I need to set up an entirely separate and parallel system to manage my environment variables locally.** This is less than ideal and feels like an uber-pain to manage. I want to be able to continue to test things quickly locally without adding a bunch of try/catch exceptions for environment variables throughout the application. I know I can import env vars all sorts of ways, but I don't want to maintain two different systems with the same info. How can I add env vars in Helm Charts while still being nimble in my Python application locally? Is there a way to import my local `values.yaml` and set them as environment variables *with the same name as in cronjob.yaml (i.e., HOST)*? Or is there another solution I am not aware of for this use-case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option you could take is to continue to allow the environment variables, but provide a default in the case that the environment variable is not set. You can do this easily with the `get()` method:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    HOST = os.environ.get('HOST', 'http://host')
    PORT = int(os.environ.get('PORT', '1234'))
    connect_to_server(HOST, PORT)
```

Comment: Are you sure you mean `os.environ.get` and not [os.getenv](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.html#os.getenv)? I don't see anything about `os.environ.get` in the docs.

Comment: Yes, I am sure. The `os.environ` object is a mapping, which supports `.get()`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Mapping. You can mostly use it the same way you would any dict.

Comment: Ah great. Thank you.